# Drupal daily summary notifications/summary

Tags: email, drupal

In Drupal is there a way to create a 'daily summary' email which collates any new content and sends the update once a day via 1 email.

I know there are rules which can be set where a single email is sent for any new content, but rather the spamming the user I was hoping to send any updates in one email per day.

I hope this makes sense.

cheers

Comment: All good I found a module which has email subscription. I used SimpleNews & SimpleNews Scheduler.